# Flipped over dataTable primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

Is it possible to flip datatable in primefaces, in order to have headers in the left not in the top?
I have following table:

```html
<p:dataTable value="#{rolesMgmt.listOfMapsRoles}" var="map" id = "dataTable">
    <p:columns value="#{rolesMgmt.columns}" var="column">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{column.header}" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{map[column.property]}" />
    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

[image]

As you see, I have a lot of headers and 2-3 rows and I need to flip this table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible by using some attribute on the `p:dataTable` itself. For this to be achieved you need to transpose your model. Maybe you can achieve something by manipulating the responsiveness. But if you have lots of columns AND lots of rows, maybe you should think of just displaying a 'summary' in a datatable and have a details view.

Or use a `p:datagrid` ([showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataGrid.xhtml)) where you can sort of free-format your records or a plain ui:repeat? Since you do not seem to need sorting/filtering etc in this case. The `p:datatable` seems overkill to me now

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to flip the table. 
Why don't you take a look to the [ColumnToggler](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/columnToggler.xhtml)? 
You can temporarly reduce the width of the table and then, on demand, add other columns.